# Connecting multiple Curator to a single Zookeeper instance?

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

Is it possible to connect multiple Curators to the same Zookeeper instance? And if so how?

It seems that Zookeeper only has a single client port.

This need arises since during tests I would need to write some init data into Zookeeper but currently I already have the main curator instance (which I do not have access to) connected to Zookeeper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're concerned about single client ports. Just allocate as many Curator instances as you want. However, why would you want more than 1 Curator instance? A single Curator instance can be used for all ZooKeeper interactions in an application. Think of it like you would a JDBC connection.

Comment: I'm assuming I'm using zookeeper incorrectly. I guess the question should be more, how do I avoid single client ports?

Comment: Again - you should explain why you want more than one client port. I can't think of a reason you'd want that.

Comment: This whole things seems to have been a mistake from my side. Understanding logs incorrectly. Sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

As Zookeeper is intended to be used by different process on different machines. By definition you will have many clients connected to the same Zookeeper, If you choose those clients to be the Curator implementation (which I recommend) then you will have different curators connected to the same ZK.

Whether those different instances are in the same process or not is irrelevant, but as Rangalt pointed out, there is no use for more than one instance per process.